# Proving $(A-B) \times C = (A \times C) - (B \times C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

For all sets $A$, $B$, and $C$, $(A-B) \times C = (A \times C) - (B \times C)$.

Does this work right to left if you're assuming $y$ is both $\in$ and $\notin C$?

Comment: You cannot simultaneously assume $y \in C$ and $y \not\in C$.

Comment: Does what work right to left?

Comment: If $x \in (A \times C) - (B \times C)$ doesn't that happen?

Comment: Is $(A \times C) - (B \times C) \subseteq (A - B) \times C$?

Comment: Yes, but you need to show that, and then the other direction.

Comment: Remember, we have the Cartesian product, so we are talking about ordered pairs here. You have to show that $(A-B) \times C \subset (A \times C) - (B \times C)$ and $(A \times C) - (B \times C) \subset (A-B) \times C$.

Comment: It must be if they are equal.

Comment: It's easy to write $(x,y) \in ( A-B)\times C $.  Then you can claim $x \in A-B$ and $y \in C $ and everything will follow nicely.

Answer (score 1):

To show $(A \times C) - (B \times C) \subset (A-B) \times C$, suppose $(x,y) \in (A \times C) - (B \times C)$.

Then $(x,y) \in A \times C$ but $ (x,y) \not\in B \times C$.

So, $x \in A$ but $x \not\in B$.

So, $x \in A-B$.

So, $(x,y) \in (A-B) \times C$.

So, $(A \times C) - (B \times C) \subset (A-B) \times C$.

---

Can you do $(A-B) \times C \subset (A \times C) - (B \times C)$?
Start with: Suppose $(x,y) \in (A-B) \times C$.